# Fastest resistive touch panel response time?

Tags: switches, touch-panel, resistive

1/ What is the fastest response time of touch panel?

2/ It seems resistive panel can get under 10ms, but I want a faster panel, is there any one with under 1ms or microsecond response time?

3/ Why electrical switch in IC can get stable in under 1ms while it takes several ms in resistive touch screen to get a stable voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Even the twitchiest gamer won't be able to distinguish 1ms so the controller does not need to measure that frequently or respond that quickly.

Resistors have an inherent time constant because of parasitic reactance but it will be much faster than 1ms for a modest size touch screen.

The mechanical touching and the controller response time are another matter.

Comment: There is de-bouncing too.  I don't know if that's an issue with resistive touch panels.    Re: Twitchy gamers.. they may not be able to "do" 1ms.. but marketing will like the specs.  "Our controllers have microsecond response times."